# batch script that tells me when was the last time a file has been accessed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a list of sales orders in a folder. I want a batch script that can output into a txt file, when were all the files last accessed but not necessarily modified.

Comment: Windows does not reliably keep track of when a file was accessesd. There are many avenues by which a file can be read, yet the last accessed info is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

On partitions with NTFS file system there are 3 file dates: creation date, last modification date and last access date.

The command

```
dir "path to directory" /TA /OD
```

lists all files of the directory according to last access date with last accessed file at bottom.

```
dir "path to directory" /TA /O-D
```

list the files in reverse order with last accessed file at top.

It is of course possible to redirect the output into a file by appending `>"Name of list file with path.log"`

But don't trust the last access time too much as it is really not reliable on when a file was last time opened for read only.

For more parameters of command `dir` open a command prompt window and enter `dir /?`

Answer (score 1):

Last Access has been turned off by default for many years.

This command shows the setting of any computer you are interested in.

```
fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
```

For using lastaccess - programs that don't open a file under user direction (eg search indexers, icon extractors like explorer, property sheets, etc) have to go back and restore last access to what it was before they opened it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Last Access Date is not reliable on NTFS. But if you wanted to extract it anyway, here is one way, but it will need a bit more parsing:

```
wmic DataFile where "Name='C:\\Users\\Default\\NTUSER.DAT'" get LastAccessed /value
```