# Windows .bat find last played date of an mp3 file

Tags: windows, batch-file, mp3

Is there any way to find the last played date/time of an mp3 file using Windows scripting?

Comment: Could you please update your question with a specific problem. This is way too broad, because well it is.

Comment: Sure, I have an MP3 file, how can I find the last played date using windows scripting batch file commands?  Output to text etc is optional.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430535/batch-script-that-tells-me-when-was-the-last-time-a-file-has-been-accessed) should help, since you can only access MP3 files by playing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was not looking for a solution to a problem, just wanted to know what the windows script command was to get the date last played.

Looping structures and if/then/else etc. were not requested, but thanks for the construct.

Here is my final script, note the /T:A which yields the time last accessed.

```
dir "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music"/T:A /4>> "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\dir.txt"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `for` loops and `forfiles` command to accomplish your task. Simply change the path to where your mp3 files are.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a count=0
set /a total=0
set /a bool=0

for /l %%i in (1,1,2) do (

    for /f %%a in ('dir /o:d c:\users\microsoft\desktop\*.mp3') do (

        if !bool! equ 0 (
            set /a total+=1
        )

        if !bool! equ 1 (

            if !count! equ !total! (
                set latest=%%a
            )
            set /a count+=1
        )
    )
    set /a bool+=1
    set /a total-=3
)

forfiles /p c:\users\microsoft\desktop /m *.mp3 /d +!latest! /c "cmd /c echo Latest mp3 ^! Enjoy ^! & echo. & echo !latest! - @file & start c:\users\microsoft\desktop\@file"

pause >nul
```

Comment: Btw you don't need `/a` when setting variable like you did at the beginning

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, this is important too, evidently Windows disables this functionality by default.  You have to tell it to start recording the last accessed time for files.  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/243272-last-access-timestamp-enable-disable-windows.html