# For & Find Command

Tags: batch-file

My script:

```
cd\
set Directory=Directory
set Filename=Filename
set Date Created=Date Created
set Date Modified=Date Modified
set Date Accessed=Date Accessed
set Size=Size

Echo %Directory%,%Filename%,%Date Created%,%Date Modified%,%Date    Accessed%,%Size% >>C:\MyText.csv

For /r C: %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") Do (
@echo %%a

For /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%b in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^| find /n " " ^| find "[6]"') Do echo %%c >>C:\MyText.csv

For /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%b in ('dir /tw "%%a" ^| find /n " " ^| find "[6]"') Do echo %%c >>C:\MyText.csv

For /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%b in ('dir /ta "%%a" ^| find /n " " ^| find "[6]"') Do echo %%c >>C:\MyText.csv
)
@pause
```

Comment: I wanted to remove [6], and only show 10/09/2018 02:22 PM xxxxx.exe

Comment: I think `echo %~ftza` would be all you need. No need no use `dir` and filtering by `find`. So after you've learned how to remove `[6]`,  I suggest you to use the learned technic where it is really needed.

Comment: Or use `echo %~nxtza` if you don't need full path information. This will more closely mimic the output format of `dir /ta`. though I'm not sure how that could be useful since you are doing a recursive search and the listed files will be from separate directories.

Comment: You're using the two `find` commands just to get the 6th line of output. Another way to do it is to use a variable in your script (let's call it `lineNumber`) and initialise it to 0, then put `set /a lineNumber += 1` inside your `for` loop and only output if it's 6. (Sorry, I haven't got time to write the code but maybe someone else can)

Comment: and how do you make sure that the 6th line is what you need? because you didn't even sort the `dir` output

Comment: I've just looked into this in more detail. The sixth line is in fact the first line that actually shows the directory details for a specific file in a `dir` output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the output of your command. At best, use another `for /f` loop for that:

```
For /r C: %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") do (
  @echo %%a
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%b in (' Dir /ta "%%a" ^| find /n " " ^| find "[6]"') do echo %%c
)
```

It splits the `dir` output into `%%b`=`[6` and `%%c`=`10/09/2018 02:22 PM   xxxxxxx.exe`

**EDIT** based on new information in the question:

first get all desired data, then echo the complete line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  Echo Directory,Filename,Date Created,Date Modified,Date Accessed,Size
  For /r C: %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") Do (
    For /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^| findstr /b "[0-9]"') Do set "tc=%%b %%c"
    For /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ('dir /tw "%%a" ^| findstr /b "[0-9]"') Do set "tw=%%b %%c"
    For /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ('dir /ta "%%a" ^| findstr /b "[0-9]"') Do set "ta=%%b %%c"
    echo %%~dpa,%%~nxa,!tc!,!tw!,!ta!,%%~za
  )
)>C:\MyText.csv
```

Redirecting is done just once to avoid to open/write/close the file for every line.

Comment: The above script does not work properly.. Please advise it again.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to escape the pipes. Try again, please.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Can I ask one more Qns?

Comment: I would need to display the file directory as well.. How can I do that?

Comment: you should provide an example of your desired output (edit it into your question). I guess, other commenters and answerers have a good point.

Comment: Please find above for my current script.

Comment: See my edit (I hope I understand your question right). I also implemented another way to get the correct line.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `find /n " " | find "[6]"` just to get the 6th line of `dir` output (which happens to be the line that lists the file details, while other lines are header and summary lines).

A simpler way to do this is as follows:

```
For /r C: %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") do (
  echo %%a
  Dir /ta %%a | find "/"
)
```

This searches for the "/" in the date that is shown on the same line as the file. This character does not appear in the header or the summary.

One caveat is that it assumes your locale uses "/" as date separator (which is the case in most countries).

By the way, last access time may not always be recorded. See this question: [batch script that tells me when was the last time a file has been accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430535/batch-script-that-tells-me-when-was-the-last-time-a-file-has-been-accessed)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you wimply want `date` and `time` or filename with it's drive and path:

simply do:

```
For /r D: %a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") do echo %~dpnta
```

see more on variable substitution when doing `for /?` from cmdline.

Comment: But that gives modification date/time, whereas dir /ta gives access date/time, do not exactly the same output.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException true, but the OP did not specify, though we could only guess he wants access time based on the /ta switch, but incase not, I am putting it out there. Thanks